# Play an image for certain time with opencv

Tags: c, image, opencv, linked-list

i want to play a presentation based on a linked list, each node has a duration time. I want to play each node for the duration time, after the duration time has reached, i want the picture to close and the node after it to play and so... How can i do it?

```html
typedef struct Link
{
    char *name;
    unsigned int duration;
    char *path;  // may change to FILE*
    struct Link *next;
}PIC;
```

Comment: You can find the current time, you know the time to wait for each frame. Find out the time when the next frame needs to show (start + duration[0]). Have a loop that keeps displaying current frame with some short wait (say 20ms). If current time is past the "next frame time", advance to next frame, recalculate the "next frame time" and repeat. | Imagine how you'd do this yourself with a clock and a bunch of cardboard signs - the algorithm is trivial.

Comment: are your questions "how to measure time" and "how to render images?" ???